# Gradient function in optim of R

Tags: r, optimization

I have two functions `f(x)` and `g(x)`. Here `f(x)` is the objective function to minimize, and `g(x)` is the gradient function. My problem is for each trial `x`, the body of `f(x)` will compute a complicated matrix `A(x)`, which will also be used in `g(x)`. For the sake of efficiency, I don't want `g(x)` to repeat the computation of `A`. I am considering to make `A(x)` global by defining `A <<- ...` in the body of `f(x)`. So `g(x)` can use `A(x)` directly. Because I don't know how `optim` in R iterates `f(x)` and `g(x)`, I am not sure if this strategy is correct and efficient. Any suggestions and comments are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You should provide a minimum working/reproducible example of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't know how `optim` is going to call `f` and `g` you are going to have to make sure that any stashed `A(x)` is from the same `x` when you need it. It might call `f(x1)`, `f(x2)`, `f(x3)` and then `g(x1)`.

One solution might be memoisation:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/index.html

A memoised `A(x)` will store the return value for given input values and return that when given the same input values without recomputing. Obviously only works for non-stochastic functions (don't call any random number generators).

I'm not sure how you control the size of the cache, but the source code is all there.